# Keep the parameters from managed Bean to a dialog open in PrimeFaces form using JSF

Tags: spring, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem training with forms in PrimeFaces. I will try to explain in the best way:

The functional idea is open a dialog in which the user can see certain inputs introduced previously.

The fact is that I need to use (save) some properties from bean which I'm managing in the view when the dialog is opened.

Example in code:

My **xhtml** says:

```
    </h:form>

        <!-- Code Here -->

        <p:commandButton value="Preview" action="#{mockBean.showPreview}"/>

        <!-- Code Here -->

        <p:dialog id="myDialog" 
                  widgetVar="myDialog" 
                  modal="true" 
                  appendToBody="true" 
                  resizable="false">
            <h:form>                        
                <p:panelGrid columns="2">

                    <!-- ...    Code Here -->   

                    <h:outputText value="Name" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{mockBean.name}" 
                                  style="display:block; 
                                  width:225px"/>    

                    <!-- ... Code Here -->

                </p:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
```

My **Bean** says:  (MockBean.java)

```
<!-- ... Code Here -->

public void showPreview(){
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
    context.execute("myDialog.show()");
}

<!-- ... Code Here -->
```

The mockBean.name property will be empty in dialog when, previously, and later, in view, the bean has a correct value

I suspect that the solution will be easy but i'm newbie in this technologies and just'm introducing to this.

Sorry if the question is absurd in part or something like that.

Greetings.

Comment: Why do you want to use another `<h:form>` tag inside a `<h:form>` tag ?

Comment: For nothing really. It's a mistake :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must update the Dialog, so it can read the saved values in your bean.

The Dialog is static, it is filled when you page is rendered, and it doesn't render again unless you tell him to do so.

You could use the `actionListener` of your `commandButton` to save the properties, combined with the `onClick="PF('myDialog').show()"` and `update="myDialog"`

Something like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save and Open Dialog" actionListener="#{mockBean.saveProperties()}" update="myDialog" onclick="PF('myDialog').show()"/>
```

Buuut, Since you are oppening the dialog from your bean, you could just try the code bellow:

```
 public void showPreview(){
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
    context.execute("myDialog.show()");
    context.update("myDialog");
}
```

Comment: It works fine. The dialog. obviously was not loading.

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, @Pellizon, maybe you can answer me about a problem that has appeared after solving this first issue.  

The question is how I could be able to open the dialog ignoring the required fields restrictions which I have placed on the form ("name", "mail", etc.)  

The solution which adds "immediate = true" in the button declaration it doesn't work fine because it seems to disable upload properly and although validation is skipped the dialog window doesn't shows the introduced bean attributes.

Comment: The problem is that you want to save the properties before opening the dialog, so the validation phase is called in that save action, unless you set the `immediate=true` (which does not work, as you said). I'm still wondering why it doesn't work, but let me try a few things and i come back with a better answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display some message from backing bean then there is no need to use another `<h:form>` tag inside a `<h:form>` tag. Your code should look something like this.

```
<h:form>

        <!-- Code Here -->

        <p:commandButton value="Preview" action="#{mockBean.showPreview}" update="myDialog" />

        <!-- Code Here -->
    <p:dialog id="myDialog" 
          widgetVar="myDialog" 
          modal="true" 
          appendToBody="true" 
          resizable="false">

       <p:panelGrid columns="2">

            <!--  Code Here --> 

            <h:outputText value="Name" />
            <h:outputText value="#{mockBean.nombre}"  
                    width:225px"/>    

            <!-- ... Code Here -->

       </p:panelGrid>

    </p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

And your java code should be as.

```
public void showPreview(){
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
    context.execute("PF('myDialog').show();");
}
```

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the recommendation Qadir.